# Kendo UI grid row filter move filter operator icon position

Tags: css, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-grid

I have a grid with very small columns with row filter, which cause them to have very small text-box. so I used

```
field: "OrderID",
   width: 100,
filterable: {
   cell: {
      inputWidth: 65
   }
}
```

but when I define inputWidth to enlarge the text field the filter operator does not move over and in fact cover up the partial space of the text-box. Therefore, I was wondering if there is a way to move the filter operator over or preferably over to the title header, like the columnMenu filter icon. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

I took the following example from:  http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-row

and modified width and inputwidth of orderID

```
<div id="example">
            <div id="grid"></div>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                        dataSource: {
                            type: "odata",
                            transport: {
                                read:"http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-  ui/service/Northwind.svc/Orders"   
                            },
                            schema: {
                                model: {
                                    fields: {
                                        OrderID: { type: "number" },
                                        Freight: { type: "number" },
                                        ShipName: { type: "string" },
                                        OrderDate: { type: "date" },
                                        ShipCity: { type: "string" }
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            pageSize: 20,
                            serverPaging: true,
                            serverFiltering: true,
                        },
                        height: 550,
                        filterable: {
                            mode: "row"
                        },
                        pageable: true,
                        columns: 
                        [{
                            field: "OrderID",
                            width: 100,
                            filterable: {
                                cell: {
                                   inputWidth: 65
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            field: "ShipName",
                            width: 500,
                            title: "Ship Name",
                            filterable: {
                                cell: {
                                    operator: "contains"
                                }
                            }
                        },{
                            field: "Freight",
                            width: 255,
                            filterable: {
                                cell: {
                                    operator: "gte"
                                }
                            }
                        },{
                            field: "OrderDate",
                            title: "Order Date",
                            format: "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}"
                        }]
                    });
                });
```

Comment: You can try removing the clear filter button after the input.

Comment: The problem is I don't want the filter operator button to appear in the middle of the input field